# Launching a readme file at the end of a Visual Studio setup project

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

This seems like it should be simple, but;

How do you launch a readme.txt/.htm automatically at the end of a Visual Studio 2008 setup project?

I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so using a custom action. The following article describes how to launch an application after installation using VS 2005. The step for VS 2008 should be identical, and simply replace the application with your readme file:

> **[Launching Your Application After Install using Visual Studio 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx)**

Please note Visual Studio setup projects are aimed at creating simple installers only. If your setup gets more complicated I'd recommend using other tools such as NSIS or WiX.